# Does django bulk_create possible exceptions

Tags: django, django-models, transactions

When using `Model.objects.bulk_create()` if an exception occurs during the insertion does it roll back the entire operation or does it continue with the non-conflicting records, and is there any way to know which records were inserted and which threw an error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If an exception occurs the entire operation will be rolled back. If you look at the [source code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/2.1.2/django/db/models/query.py#L456) you'll see that all database operations are wrapped in `transaction.atomic()`.

There's no way of knowing which values caused the conflict. Such information may be available in the database-specific error message, but that's not part of the API.

Note that as of Django 2.2 there will be an [`ignore_conflicts`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.bulk_create) parameter that will allow you to explicitly control whether the operation will roll back or whether the conflicts will be ignored.